# Can't get intellisense on angular-cli.json file

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular-cli

All help online I have found so far shows people who properly have intellisense(autocomplete) in the angular-cli.json file in order to reference resources.

I can't understand why I always get "No suggestions." when I press "ctrl+space".

I have all the following extensions installed in the Visual Studio Code.

Any direction is appreciated:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by installing this Extension:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine with the latest version of Angular-Cli. Anyhow you can refer the related issue from the  [`Autocomplete No Longer Works With Angular 6`](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/256)